# Command- and InputBindings in a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a WPF UserControl that I'm trying to adapt to my program with kind of a MVVM pattern. Now the problem is, that the UserControl uses Command- and InputBindings which I can't simply apply to a DataTemplate. What options do I have to implement the same functionality without even having a code-behind?

Here's the XAML as of right now:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Settings"
                xmlns:elements="clr-namespace:MyProject.Settings.Elements"
                xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
                xmlns:dataPresenter="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"
                xmlns:igEditors="http://infragistics.com/Editors"
                xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
<DataTemplate x:Key="PrioritySettingTemplate" DataType="{x:Type elements:PrioritySetting}">
    <ContentPresenter>
        <ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Gesture="Delete" Key="Delete"
                        Command="{Binding TestCommand}" />
        </ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type elements:PrioritySetting}">
                    <!--
                        Main part of the UserControl
                    -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You can create another template with ContentPresenter, apply bindings to it and set ContentTemplate to the first template. It would be helpful if you could post some code, because right now it is not exactly clear what is your problem is.

Comment: I've updated the question with the XAML (minus some parts that I think are not relevant to the question) after I tried a bit with the ContentPresenter and ContentTemplate. I think that could work, but right now I'm having a bit of a trouble putting everything in the right order. In the end I just want to pass a class to my UI and have the template automatically be applied to it.

Comment: Oh, ok. I think you are ovethinking this a little bit. Just put your control in the topmost template, set `InputBindings` on it, and set `DataType`, but not the key. Now, if you bind your Content property to the relevant property of relevant type, it will use your template. This is called implicit templates.

Comment: I don't know if I completely followed your instructions, but I think I got it now (https://pastebin.com/xaeCJzGX). The Control shows up in the program and the InputBinding works as expected. Thank you for your help!

Comment: [Why not simplify it?](https://pastebin.com/heDpQUKt)

Comment: Earlier I was just happy over any solution, even if it was more complicated, but I'm doing it like that now. Thanks again!